# laravel search multiple keywords

Tags: laravel

I have a problem with search form on my website. Basically, when user will type multiple keywords to search form (e.g. business card ) then search result will show all images from keyword 1 (e.g. business) and all images from keyword2 (e.g. card). This is bad, the search form is not relevant at all. Can you please look at the code down bellow and help me fix it so the search form will show only images with both keywords together (keyword1 + AND + keyword2).

```
public function search($search, $category = null, $timeframe = null)
    {
        $extends = explode(' ', $search);
        if ($category) {
            $categoryId = $this->category->whereSlug($category)->first();
        }
        $images = $this->posts($category, $timeframe)->where('title', 'LIKE', '%' . $search . '%')
        ->orWhere('tags', 'LIKE', '%' . $search . '%')
        ->whereNull('deleted_at')->whereNotNull('approved_at')->orderBy('approved_at', 'desc');

        foreach ($extends as $extend) {
            if (isset($categoryId)) {
                $images->whereCategoryId($categoryId)->Where('tags', 'LIKE', '%' . $extend . '%')->whereNotNull('approved_at')->whereNull('deleted_at')
                ->whereCategoryId($categoryId)->orWhere('title', 'LIKE', '%' . $search . '%')->whereNotNull('approved_at')->whereNull('deleted_at')
                ->whereCategoryId($categoryId)->orWhere('image_description', 'LIKE', '%' . $search . '%')->whereNotNull('approved_at')->whereNull('deleted_at');
            } else {
                $images->orWhere('tags', 'LIKE', '%' . $extend . '%')->whereNotNull('approved_at')->whereNull('deleted_at')
                ->orWhere('title', 'LIKE', '%' . $search . '%')->whereNotNull('approved_at')->whereNull('deleted_at')
                ->orWhere('image_description', 'LIKE', '%' . $search . '%')->whereNotNull('approved_at')->whereNull('deleted_at');
            }
        }

        return $images = $images->with('user', 'comments', 'favorites')->whereNotNull('approved_at')->whereNull('deleted_at')->paginate(perPage());
    }
```

Comment: uh.. any description on how it works..? at least, give us a clue on original data example, current output, and expected output.. anyway, you should check `->orWhere('tags', 'LIKE', '%' . $extend . '%')`, i suppose..

Answer (score 0):

When you use the `%` sign before and after the search query, you say "give me anything with that items", if you want your system to search and give results exactly as per what the user has entered, you should use only the key phrase. try the code below.

```
     public function search($search, $category = null, $timeframe = null)
    {
        $extends = explode(' ', $search);
        if ($category) {
            $categoryId = $this->category->whereSlug($category)->first();
        }
        $images = $this->posts($category, $timeframe)
        ->where('title', 'LIKE',  "$search")
        ->orWhere('tags', 'LIKE', "$search")
        ->whereNull('deleted_at')
        ->whereNotNull('approved_at')
        ->orderBy('approved_at', 'desc');

        foreach ($extends as $extend) {
            if (isset($categoryId)) {
                $images->whereCategoryId($categoryId)->Where('tags', 'LIKE', "$search")
                ->whereNotNull('approved_at')->whereNull('deleted_at')
                ->whereCategoryId($categoryId)->orWhere('title', 'LIKE', "$search")
                ->whereNotNull('approved_at')->whereNull('deleted_at')
                ->whereCategoryId($categoryId)
->orWhere('image_description', 'LIKE', "$search")
                ->whereNotNull('approved_at')->whereNull('deleted_at');
            } 
            else {
                $images->orWhere('tags', 'LIKE', "$extend")
                ->whereNotNull('approved_at')->whereNull('deleted_at')
                ->orWhere('title', 'LIKE', "$search")
                ->whereNotNull('approved_at')->whereNull('deleted_at')
                ->orWhere('image_description', 'LIKE', "$search")
                ->whereNotNull('approved_at')->whereNull('deleted_at');
            }
        }
        return $images = $images->with('user', 'comments', 'favorites')
        ->whereNotNull('approved_at')
        ->whereNull('deleted_at')
        ->paginate(perPage());
    }
```